# The requested member of the collection does not exist error in word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use a macro to generate an invoice number, then insert it in a specific place, then save the document as the newly generated number. I have the code below but when I try to run it, it comes back with an error that says "The requested member of the collection does not exist."

```
Sub CreateInvoiceNumber()
Invoice = System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\Chad\Documents\BOLTemplate\" & _
    "invoice-number.txt", "InvoiceNumber", "Invoice")

If Invoice = "" Then
    Invoice = 1
Else
    Invoice = Invoice + 1
End If

System.PrivateProfileString("C:\Users\Chad\Documents\BOLTemplate\" & _
    "invoice-number.txt", "InvoiceNumber", "Invoice") = Invoice

'Insert the number in the document

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(“Invoicenan”).Range.InsertBefore Format(Invoice, "")

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
 "C:\Users\Chad\Documents\BOLTemplate\inv" & Format(Invoice, "") & ".docx" _
 , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
 AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
 EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
 :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14

End Sub
```

I believe the error is in this line because it will generate the number, but won't insert it.

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(“Invoicenan”).Range.InsertBefore Format(Invoice, "")
```

Any thoughts as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Does your active document have a Bookmark named "Invoicenan"?

Comment: @xidgel Yes the document does have a bookmark named "Invoicenan".

Comment: That line of code `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks...` works for me. Are you sure there's not a typo, extra white space, etc. in your bookmark name?

Comment: And when I intentionally mis-spell the bookmark name `Bookmarks("InvoiceMan")` I can reproduce the "member of the collection does not exist" error.

Comment: I just noticed `“Invoicenan”` in your code is wrapped in *curly* quotes --- maybe those need to be **straight** quotes `"Invoicenan"`.

Comment: @xidgel The bookmark matches the bookmark name. Good catch but after changing the quotes like you said, I get a new error. "Object doesn't support this property or method." Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm stumped --- your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me, so this is more of a debugging approach than an answer. To isolate the problem I would try breaking things down into tiny steps to isolate the failure. Something like:

```
Debug.Print "The active document is" " & ActiveDocument.Name

Dim wd as Word.Document
Set wd = ActiveDocument
Debug.Print "The document being created is" " & wd.Name

Dim bk as Word.Bookmark
Debug.Print "This document has these bookmarks"
For Each bk in wd.Bookmarks
    Debug.Print bk.Name
    If bk.Name = "Invoicenan" Then
        Debug.Print "It's a match!"
        Dim r as Word.Range
        Set r = bk.Range
        r.InsertBefore Format(Invoice, "")
    End If
Next bk
```

If no matches are found, then drill down into that. Compare the lengths of "Invoicenan" and the bookmark that is supposed to match. If they match, do a char by char comparison, Etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have done a little debugging. I put a line of code in there that was supposed to find the bookmark "Invoicenan" then put the curser there, and it did it correctly.

Comment: The code works for me --- this is strange??? As a workaround, since you can move the cursor to the bookmark, maybe you can then use the `Selection` object to insert your text.